# Different hiera hierarchy per dynamic environment

Tags: puppetmaster, hiera, hierarchy

Is it possible to define a separate *hiera.yaml* for a given environment? Currently I am using [dynamic environments](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/git-workflow-and-puppet-environments). Each one has its own hiera data directory, per my *hiera.yaml* file.

```
:yaml:
   :datadir: /var/lib/hiera/%{environment}
```

One drawback though is all of these environments are subject to the same hierarchy. I don't think this would work very well with many teams on a shared Puppet master.

So what is the best option, a dedicated Puppet master for each team that has a set of servers to maintain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just [found it](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#hieraconfig).

My guess is you can make this *dynamic* in the same way as *environments*, something like

```
hiera_config = $confdir/environments/$environment/hiera.yaml
```